# Combobox Visiblecolumn binding

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, visible

I'm writing a tool that creates code (e.g : Code generator). However, there is the following method **deletes** the Visible Column binding in Combobox . (WPF)
 Method :

```
 public static string ConvertControlToString<T>(T orig)
    {
        StringBuilder outstr = new StringBuilder();
        //this code need for right XML fomating 
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
        XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(outstr, settings));
        //this string need for turning on expression saving mode 
        dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
        XamlWriter.Save(orig, dsm);
        return outstr.ToString();
    }
```

In this method, I arrive at the following expression.

panel.ContentXamlString = EditorHelper.ConvertControlToString(c.Content);

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This method delete the my combobox visiblecolumn binding . i dont want this .